# fulltext search over data with underscore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a indexed table where one of the indexed columns can contains data with an underscore.

```
ID  Name
1   01_A3L
2   02_A3L
3   03_A3L
4   05_A3L
5   some name
6   another name
7   a name
```

When I search this table with the following query however I don't get any results:

```
SELECT * FROM MyAmazingTable WHERE( CONTAINS(*,'"a3l*"'))
```

What is the reason for this? And how can I make sure I do get results I expect (all records that end with A3L)?

Comment: By default, SQL server ignores most symbols and special characters. You can configure SQL Server to stop considering the underscore character as a "noise word" by removing it from the noise.dat file in your server's full text index configuration folder (typically C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL\FTDATA\SQLServer\Config). Scroll down to the bottom of the noise.dat file and delete the "_" character. you will have to rebuild your full-text catalogs for it to take effect. (Source: http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49593)

Comment: A possible location is: $SQL_Server_Install_Path\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\FTDATA\. 20 different languages are supported from Chinese (Noisechs.txt) to Turkish (Noisetrk.txt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kees C Bakker is 100% correct, but if you just wanted to get the results you require without all of the steps.
The quick/dirty way to do so would be change your search to be a like...
Select * from MyAmazingTable where Name like '%A3L'
The % in this case would represent whatever comes before and make sure the last 3 characters are A3L.
Which will give you the results that you are looking for.